# Merge columns from two SQL query results with different number of columns

Tags: sql

I've two tables which have following columns:

[image: ERD]

Now I want have a SQL query which gives me an output as follows:
[image: SQL output]

I wrote already some SQL code, but this doesn't work because the union operator needs the same number of columns with the same type. Have a look.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT User_tbl1.Username, User_tbl1.Surname, User_tbl1.Givename
FROM User_tbl1
UNION
SELECT User_tbl2.User_PK
FROM User_tbl2)
```

Can someone help me to bring my SQL query working, so that it will output a hyphen at surname and givename if the record is located in table "User_tbl2"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your UNION clause is totally wrong... Post some sample data and ur desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as:

```
SELECT User_tbl1.Username, User_tbl1.Surname, User_tbl1.Givename
FROM User_tbl1
UNION
SELECT User_tbl2.User_PK, '-', '-'
FROM User_tbl2
```